# C++ Windows API перерисовать когда курсор в зоне

Tags: c++, winapi

В WM_PAINT рисуется Rectangle (GDI+). Как изменить толщину края Rectangle когда курсор наведен на него и вернуть обратно когда нет? Изначально толщину задаю в Pen. Проверить наведение на Rectangle удалось в WM_MOUSEMOVE, но pen.SetWidth в WM_MOUSEMOVE или не работает или работает но нет перерисовки

Comment: Ну правильно, наведение проверять в WM_MOUSEMOVE, а выставлять толщину линии и рисовать  в WM_PAINT

Comment: ну а как перерисовать когда проверил?)

Comment: Инвалидировать окно вызвав `InvalidateRect` например.

Comment: а нормально его редравить в mouse move?

Comment: и оно белым мерцает. Как убрать?

Comment: 1) не нормально, 2) рисуйте с буферизацией

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже ответили в комментариях, в обработчике `WM_MOUSEMOVE` нужно вызывать функцию `InvalidateRect`. Больше ничего не нужно, обработчик `WM_PAINT` все сделает сам.

Это решение имеет очевидные недостатки: 1) неэффективность, и 2) мерцание. Можно сделать сложнее, но лучше.

В обработчике `WM_MOUSEMOVE`:

1) Функцией `CreateRectRgn` создать два прямоугольных региона - первый включает себя область полностью, второй только внутреннюю часть без границы.

2) Функцией `CombineRgn` с аргументом `RGN_DIFF` создать разность регионов. Результирующий регион будет содержать только границу.

3) Вызвать `InvalidateRgn` (не `InvalidateRect`!). Таким образом, будет запрошено обновление только границы. Причем аргумент `bErase` должен быть FALSE, иначе будет мелькание в области границы.

*Примечание: разумеется, это надо делать только тогда, когда курсор вошел в зону или вышел из зоны. То есть некий флажок должен хранить текущее состояние границы, и его надо проверять, прежде чем затевать перерисовку.*

В обрабочике `WM_PAINT`:

1) Получить регион обновления функцией `GetUpdateRgn`.

2) Полученный регион использовать как аргумент функции `SelectClipRgn`.

3) Дальше обновлять обычным образом. Будет обновляться только граница (и прочие измененные области, если такие есть).

Можно пойти дальше и сделать обновление еще эффективней. Для этого нужно в `WM_PAINT` построить регион границы (как это делалось в `WM_MOUSEMOVE`) и найти его XOR с результатом функции `GetUpdateRgn`. Если XOR этих регионов даст в результате пустой регион, значит было запрошено обновление только границы, и ее можно просто отрисовать пером, само окно обновлять не нужно. Ну а если регион не пустой, значит нужно, как описано выше, установить клипинг и рисовать.